# Approaches for assessing if categorical exposure varies over time

Tags: regression, time-series, mixed-model, interaction, interpretation

I have received two differing recommendations on analyzing whether a categorical variable X varies over time when I have a continuous outcome Y measured at multiple time points:

**Approach 1**:

- Prespecify a model including the interaction term X*time along with main effects.
- Fit this model and report the results for X*time regardless of significance.
- The X*time coefficient directly answers whether X varies over time.

**Approach 2**:

- Build one model with X*time plus main effects.
- Build a second model excluding X*time but retaining the main effects.
- Use a likelihood ratio test to compare the two models.
- If the more complex model with X*time does not significantly improve model fit, conclude that X does not vary over time.

Would appreciate guidance on which is the better method when interested in causal inference (not prediction).